# why we are using the ../../../wp-load.php in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Sorry for asking this type of stupid ques.
But i don't know I need your help
I look out the coding that they are in wordpress plugin.

```
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
```

I really don't know what the ../../.. is perform some one know ,let me give an suggestion
I am not tell about the core file and all .that extension before the php file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That loads the WordPress framework for use outside of the native environment.

For example, if you wanted to have a PHP controller that handled AJAX requests, you could load the WordPress environment to validate the current WordPress user login status.

The "../../.." tells the require function to start at the current file, go up three directories, then access wp-load.php.

Based on that path, I can guess that the file is sitting in a theme folder. `wp-content/themes/yourtheme`

Comment: great thanks . why we are linking the code through .. extension what they perform.